# Joomla - Upgrade Version 3.2.3 to 3.4.7

Tags: joomla, upgrade, joomla3.0

Recently, we have done Penetration testing for our Joomla site and came across below Vulnerabilities

```
Joomla Core Remote Code Execution Vulnerability
Solution : Upgrade to version 3.4.6
```

Reference: [Core Remote Code Execution Vulnerability](https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/12/joomla-remote-code-execution-the-details.html)

AND

```
Web application potentially vulnerable to clickjacking
Solution: Return the X-Frame options HTTP header with the page's response
```

We have outlined some Action Items as below

- Our server meet the minimum technical requirements for Joomla `3.4.7`
  as its already running version `3.2.3`
- List down all third-party extensions in use. This includes
  components, modules, plugins, languages, and templates.
- Determine whether the third-party extensions we rely on are ready for
  the version of Joomla we are migrating to.

Migrating from **2.5** to **3.x** is mini-migration which is already done in our case.

1. How do we go about upgrading from **3.2.3 to 3.4.7** ?
2. How do we upgrade **Database** ?
3. If upgrade is done successfully, how do we test all the
   **components/extensions/modules** ?
4. Any official guidelines available to perform the operation?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Joomla in the 3.x series is a one click action as described here https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Updating_from_an_existing_version.

I suggest doing a backup first with akeeba backup and then transferring the site to a test server. There you can do the upgrade and test if all the extensions are working as expected. If all is fine, then upgrade the production site.

Most problems do happen with template overrides in your template. Check them and disable them during the upgrade. After the upgrade is done enable them one by one.

Comment: The question is about upgrading to version 3.4.7 and not the latest version which is 3.5. How do do it manually including changes to the database ? Is it essential updating all extensions to their latest versions too as its a minor upgrade only ?

Comment: Ok, didn't read it carefully. Then download it from here https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.4.8/Joomla_3.4.8-Stable-Update_Package.zip and install it trough the extension manager

Comment: The download could be done from https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/tag/3.4.7. But how to migrate DB, components, extensions and media is not mentioned anywhere. If could edit the same in your answer

Comment: DB upgrade is done automatically, normally in patch releases no database upgrade is required. Extensions are difficult, you don't know if you didn't try it. Normally they work across Joomla minor versions. Media normally doesn't need to be upgraded in minor releases.